# Yosemite printer panasonic DP C265 not print. Says: "Stopped - 'Filter' failed"

Tags: mac, printing

```
21/04/15 22:14:15,014 powerd[48]: FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "(null)".
21/04/15 22:14:19,195 sandboxd[405]: ([1457]) foomatic-rip(1457) deny file-read-data /usr/local/etc/foomatic/filter.conf
21/04/15 22:14:19,233 _192_168_15_20[1455]: The function ‘CGContextErase’ is obsolete and will be removed in an upcoming update. Unfortunately, this application, or a library it uses, is using this obsolete function, and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system performance.
21/04/15 22:14:19,579 sandboxd[405]: ([1461]) sh(1461) deny file-read-data /dev/tty
21/04/15 22:14:19,598 sandboxd[405]: ([1461]) sh(1461) deny file-read-data /
21/04/15 22:14:19,619 sandboxd[405]: ([1465]) bash(1465) deny file-read-data /dev/tty
21/04/15 22:14:19,638 sandboxd[405]: ([1465]) bash(1465) deny file-read-data /
21/04/15 22:15:15,015 powerd[48]: FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "(null)".
```

Comment: and this is your printer 192_168_15_20[1455] ?

Comment: Means get an updated driver.

Comment: The file read is being sandboxed - whatever is calling the file is possibly using a string ref not a POSIX file ref. The 1st line would appear to confirm that guess.

Comment: "Sandboxing Off" seems to not work, in El Capitan (Mac OS 10.11) anyway. According to this page:
https://www.papercut.com/kb/Main/MacOS1010YosemiteKnownIssues
the correct syntax is "Sandboxing Relaxed"
However, neither of these seems to enable my computer to print.

Answer (score 1):

It IS being sandboxed. One solution is to disable sandboxing:

> Edit /etc/cups/cups-files.conf and add this line: "Sandboxing Off",
>   restart cups: "sudo launchctl stop org.cups.cupsd"

However, another user has written a script which identifies those printer descriptions which need explicit path/to/file information, and automagically adds it.

I have used this script to allow me to print to my HP 5850 from Yosemite. My other printers (modern drivers) were not affected.

This solution is not mine. I found this answer through others' answers here  (https://discussions.apple.com/message/26887951#26887951). Good luck!

Comment: Hi Parradoxx, welcome to Ask Different. Please add the script here if you can, and credit the author (as you appear to have done). Links tend to get broken.